# form validation with bootstrap with integer

Tags: javascript, validation

Trying to make the value validate as integer and is it possible to make it validate as decimal ? As 23,34 (two in front and two after comma)..

```
jsfiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5WMff/320/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery.validator.addMethod() method for this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('decimal', function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^\d+(\,\d{2,2})?$/.test(value); 
}, "Wrong number format, please enter xx.xx value");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JWF7M/)

Comment: That fiddle link goes to my fiddle. You have to update it to generate another link.

Comment: If I only want it to validate a integer or decimal. How would the method be for those two ? Because the method described is able to use both integer and decimal.

Comment: for integers only you use this regex: /^\d+$/ and for decimals only this one : /^[0-9]*\,[0-9]{2}$/